# How to make test cases for methods returning large data

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

The application generates CSV's, custom/tab delimeter etc. reports & to make test case of these reports, I am using JUnit-4.

But some methods return huge data as a formatted output string, which has to be dumped in file. Now, I am facing issue for generating expected result for assertion.

1. Then how to simulate it, do I need to write code again, which is enourmous.
2. Is it a good practice to code(re-code as original) in JUnit, which I certainly doubt.   It will be tightly coupled & test case fail in future if code changes.
3. How to make test case for method returning huge list, I can restrict it to some hundreds, but not able to mock expected result list to compare with it.
4. Also, I am using JUnit for testing the functionality of web-based application at application layer, not at the view layer. Is it fine or should I move to other framework like HttpUnit.

---

**Edit :** I am testing a method which takes input as ArrayList fetched from the database & then prepares output as properly formatted string for report. So basically, it generates CSV from data.

Also, can someone point few must-followed best practices for unit-testing. I have gone through various online resources, but can't relate much.

Comment: What exactly are you testing? A method which returns data (from where? a database? and based on what?), or a method which generates CSV from data?

Comment: @JBNizet Edited post to add more information

Comment: @NayanWadekar based on your edit, your method seems to only do some formatting. That's what you need to test. Testing it on "production" data is not necessary at the unit test level. So create several (short) arraylists representative of the various cases that can arise and check that the output is as expected.

Comment: @assylias Yes, I am managing to reduce the results but still, the problamatic part is formatting & arranging the data into that manually. Please refer my comment at JBNizet's post.

Answer (score 1):

The method you're unit testing is a method which takes data as argument, and transforms it into CSV. So it should just test that this transformation works, and you should feed it with the minimal necessary data to verify that it indeed works, for all cases.

This method should be independant of the method which fetches the data from the database, and you should not fetch an enormous amount of data from the database to unit-test this method. Just prepare the data in memory, and give it as an argument to your data-transformation method in your test:

```
List<Foo> data = new ArrayList<Foo>();
data.add(createFooA());
data.add(createFooB());
String csv = myTestedObject.transformToCsv(data);
assertEquals("...", csv);
```

Comment: I am getting issue in generating "...", which is very complex part, its a report which contains monthly/daily totals, headers etc. Its very difficult to generate such string manually with several rows having delimiters. Single space mismatch would make the test case fail.

Comment: One option is to verify (visually) that the CSV file generated by the test looks right, to save it as a file in your test package tree, and to change your test code to compare the generated data with the saved CSV file.

Comment: I have already tried that, comparing both the files. But still have to feed data manually into that each time, as data gets changed frequently.

Comment: @NayanWadekar if your method also calculates the totals then it's probably doing too many things which makes it harder to test. If the sums are done in the query, then that's where you need to test the result, not in the csv generator.

Comment: Also: why would the data change frequently? There's no need to change the test data unless the contract of the CSV transformation method changes. Remember: test data is not supposed to be production data. It's supposed to be data sufficient to test that the method does what it's supposed to do, and nothing else.